Identity column feature in delta not working in Spark SQL(Without using Databricks)
I'm currently using Spark SQL without Databricks. I'm trying to utilize Identity Column Feature in Spark SQL. But this is not working for me.
Can this be utilized without Databricks? I am currently using deltalake which is an opensource. And I think even Databricks uses DeltaLake https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html
I'm trying to run this code:
spark.sql(f'''
    CREATE TABLE {database}.{table_name} (
        regionkey BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1), 
        regionname STRING
    )
    USING DELTA
    LOCATION '{target_csv_delta_path}'
''')

It throws an error:
\`An error was encountered:
ParseException
\[Traceback (most recent call last):
,   File "/tmp/spark-669d5c85-0c49-4963-9061-7b776140f49b/shell_wrapper.py", line 113, in exec
self.\_exec_then_eval(code)
,   File "/tmp/spark-669d5c85-0c49-4963-9061-7b776140f49b/shell_wrapper.py", line 106, in \_exec_then_eval
exec(compile(last, '\<string\>', 'single'), self.globals)
,   File "\<string\>", line 1, in \<module\>
,   File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1440, in sql
return DataFrame(self.\_jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery, litArgs), self)
,   File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
return_value = get_return_value(
,   File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 175, in deco
raise converted from None
, pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.ParseException:
\[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR\] Syntax error at or near 'IDENTITY'.(line 3, pos 25)

== SQL ==

    CREATE TABLE schema123.test (
        regionkey BIGINT IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1), 

\-------------------------^^^
regionname STRING
)
USING DELTA
LOCATION 'abfss:pathToWrite'

Spark Version = 3.4.2
Expectations:
To utilize identity column without using Databricks.
Alternatives:
I know there exists alternatives such as row_number() / monotonically_increasing_id, etc. But I wanted to utilize this feature.
Please help.
Important Links that I went through:
Create Table Syntax for generated columns
Identity Column in Databricks Spark SQL

Currently opensource delta.io doesn't have support for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY column in DeltaTableBuilder.
There is an open issue on Github for the same:
https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1072  and it might be developed in the upcoming versions.
If you don't want to use Databricks, the alternative is to use monotonically_increasing_id or row_number() for your local setup
